# Solr vs document encoding problems

Tags: java, character-encoding, solr

I am using solrj 1.4. My solrj doesn't index properly the documents in utf-16 encoding. I guess when it tries to convert to unicode, it replaces the problematic utf-16 surrogate keys with unicode replaceable character U+FFFD. Can anyone guide me on how to configure solrj 1.4 to index/search for utf-16 documents as well as utf-8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solr index is in utf-8 ([Why don't International Characters Work](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F)). In order to be able to search using other encodings you can always perform the translation in your software interfacing Solr.

Comment: Conversion from utf-16 to utf-8 is always 100% successful. Is there any fool proof method or api available ?

Comment: Fool proof I don't know, but [CharsetEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) is typically handy.